# Should I perform train_test_split first and then GridSearchCV and then K Fold Crossvalidation?

Tags: gridsearchcv, train-test-split, k-fold

I am having a lot of confusion between GridSearchCV and K fold Cross Validation. I know that GridSearch is only for hyperparameter optimization and K Fold will split my data into K folds and iterate over them (cv value). So should I first split my data into train and validation sets, apply GridSearch on training data for "best parameters" and then use K Fold on my training data using the "best parameters" I got from GridSearch and then finally train model on whole data(train + validation set)? Or is there some other order of doing the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my understanding, you do not have to perform KFold before GridSearchCV.

GridSearchCV has a cross validation parameter which performs cross validation.